# Any reasons why I can't replace ISNULL(col, literal) NOT LIKE literal with col <> literal if literal contains no wildcards?

Tags: t-sql, sql-like

I've come across, some old code, something like this example:

```
    DECLARE @tmpVal INT = 999

    DECLARE @tmpTable TABLE (col1 INT, col2 VARCHAR(20))

    INSERT INTO @tmpTable (col1, col2)
    VALUES 
        (1, 'Do not want this'),
        (2, 'Happy with this'),
        (3, NULL)

    SELECT
        col1,
        col2,
        -- I see code like this
        CASE
            WHEN ISNULL(col2, 'Do not want this') NOT LIKE 'Do not want this'
            THEN @tmpVal
        END                                                 AS CurrentCol,

        -- can I replace it with code like this because there is no else?
        CASE
            WHEN col2 <> 'Do not want this'
            THEN @tmpVal
        END                                                 AS BetterCol

    FROM 
        @tmpTable
```

My thinking is that `ISNULL(col2, 'Do not want this') NOT LIKE 'Do not want this'` should be replaced with `col2 <> 'Do not want this'` as it handles the null case perfectly.

[image]

Can I use the form in BetterCol over CurrentCol as the WHEN expression and if not why? Are there any edge cases I'm not seeing?

Comment: It's rare to use a `LIKE` without a special character like `%`, `_`, etc. Make sure that there isn't one so you can replace the expression safely. You will also potentially benefit from indexes as the `ISNULL` would void their use because of applying functions to the tracking column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR; - Yes, you can replace it - it's (almost) perfectly safe.

The longer version:

In SQL Server, unless [`SET ANSI_NULL OFF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-nulls-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is specified (and it really shouldn't be specified ever - note that it's deprecated) - any comparison of anything to a `null` will result with an `UNKNOWN`, which is basically equivalent to `false` for `case` expressions or `where` clause predicates.

This means that `SomeValue <> NULL` and `SomeValue = NULL` and even `NULL = NULL` and `NULL <> NULL` will all return `UNKNOWN`

Though I didn't find any documentation of the behavior of `NULL` and the `LIKE` operator (I've searched in `SET ANSI_NULL`, [`LIKE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [`NULL` and `UNKNOWN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/null-and-unknown-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) documentation) it is a well known fact that the behavior of `null` is the same with the `like` operator as it is with the `=` operator - meaning `NULL LIKE 'some string'` will return `UNKNOWN` as well.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah we're using ANSI nulls - hence the reason me trying to understand why the code wasn't written that way already!